# Why the x-axis start from 91 instead of 90?

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import MultipleLocator
plt.axis([90, 155, 45, 90])
x_major_locator=MultipleLocator(13)
y_major_locator=MultipleLocator(9)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_major_locator)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(y_major_locator)
plt.show()
```

[Why the x-axis start from 91 instead of 90??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvg2U.png)

Comment: `MultipleLocator(13)` only sets ticks at multiples of 13, there doesn't seem to be an option for an offset.  It isn't so weird. Suppose you set `MultipleLocator(10)` and your x-axis would start at `9.8765`, it is usually expected that the ticks are nicely at the round multiples of `10`, instead of starting with the left x limit.

Comment: Your answer makes sense for me thanks! But how can I obtain a set of x ticks as [90, 103, 116, 129, 142, 155]? It starts at 90 and end at 155 with an increment of 13.

Comment: With a `FixedLocator(np.arange(90, 156, 13))`?